# Dockerfile container working on Mac but not Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have a Dockerfile that we use to create a container for development. It is working fine for me on my Mac but my co-worker on Windows it is not mounting the local development directory. When he enters the container through bash, it shows an empty directory. It seems like the local directory is not mounted. Is there some kind of thing we should do specifically for Windows?

This is my Dockerfile, which is placed in the root of the project

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN apk update

RUN apk add nano bash bash-completion

# Set Working Directory
WORKDIR /var/www/api

COPY . .

ENV ENV="/root/.bashrc"
RUN echo 'alias ll="ls -lhat"' >> /root/.bashrc
RUN echo 'export PS1="\[\e[0;32m\][MM_PLAY] \w\$\[\e[0m\] "' >> /root/.bashrc

CMD ["node", "./bin/www"]
```

The docker-compose file

```
version: '3.2'

services: 
  api:
    build: ../../
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
      - "7331:7331"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../../
        target: /var/www/api
    command: bash
    #command: yarn start
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    container_name: mm

networks: 
  default:
    external:
      name: database_default
```

Comment: You have to do some kind of setup, before you can mount directories in docker for windows:  https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you have to do some additional steps to make volumes work on Windows: https://rominirani.com/docker-on-windows-mounting-host-directories-d96f3f056a2c